# Google MAP API V3 cannot clear the previous mutiple routes history

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This is the alternative route function, while when I redirect with other direction. It can not clear the previous route.

```
function initialize() {

// Create a new map with some default settings
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8602828,145.079616);
var myOptions = {
  zoom:8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 //click function call calculateAndDisplayRoute to ge the alternative routes
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;



        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {

            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, map);

        });


//this function used to calculate the alternative route.
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, map) {     

//get the value from start and end input box 
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
var end =document.getElementById('end').value;

//property when dran on the map
var directionsRequest = {
   //starting point
    origin: start,
    //destination
    destination: end,
    //multiple route
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

};

directionsService.route( directionsRequest, function(response, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         //store the multiple routes in respones and display one by one
         for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
              new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map,
                directions: response,
                routeIndex: i
              });
        }

    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: related question: [Remove route google maps API using button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290379/remove-route-google-maps-api-using-button)

Comment: related question: [Clearing multiple direction results of a google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706907/clearing-multiple-direction-results-of-a-google-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: @geocodezip, thank you so much, hope it is not too late.

Comment: @geocodezip, I remember used the global variables in javascript. Just like the directions = []; .  Assign a new value to it in a function and read the variable again in another function. But the variable is always empty. How can you do that. Thank you

Comment: @geocodezip if  put "console.log(directions.length);" before  "document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener". What it always show 0 in console panel.

Comment: What is `directions`?  I don't see that in the posted code...

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry, I meant your code below  // in the global scope
 directions = [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change/remove the rendered directions, you need to keep references to the `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` objects that you use to display directions on the map and remove them from the map before losing that reference.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7dq9xL8L/)

```
 // in the global scope
 directions = [];

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
if (directions && directions.length > 0) {
  for (var i=0; i<directions.length; i++)
     directions[i].setMap(null);
  }
  directions = [];
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, map);
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var directions = [];

function initialize() {

  // Create a new map with some default settings
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8602828, 145.079616);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  //click function call calculateAndDisplayRoute to ge the alternative routes
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;



  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (directions && directions.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < directions.length; i++)
        directions[i].setMap(null);
    }
    directions = [];
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, map);

  });


  //this function used to calculate the alternative route.
  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, map) {

    //get the value from start and end input box 
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;

    //property when dran on the map
    var directionsRequest = {
      //starting point
      origin: start,
      //destination
      destination: end,
      //multiple route
      provideRouteAlternatives: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

    };

    directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {

      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        //store the multiple routes in respones and display one by one
        for (var i = 0, len = response.routes.length; i < len; i++) {
          directions.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map,
            directions: response,
            routeIndex: i
          }));
        }

      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" value="get directions" id="submit" />
<input value="New York, NY" id="start" />
<input value="Newark, NJ" id="end" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```